# How has ChatGPT changed WP StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

Are there less complex WP questions being posted due to ChatGPT able to answer these?
Are there more ChatGPT styled answers appearing?
Has there been any other trends/changes since the release of ChatGPT?

Comment: questions about the stack itself should go on the meta stack

Comment: I've moved it here, but this is the WordPress stack, not the overall stack exchange meta stack. _Note that ChatGPT answers were banned not long after its introduction_

Comment: I have not noticed any significant impact, except that occasionally a question gets posted because ChatGPT gave them broken code that didn't work.

Comment: Appears to be a ChatGPT user: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/235234/akshatlive

Answer (score 0):

We are just seeing the beginning, I'm afraid. I just flagged [a ChatGPT generated answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/270666) (the German tagline gave it away), generated by a new user. If you look at their profile, you will see that it has a link to a linktr.ee that contains spam links. Other links in the profile are muddled because of some technical error.

If this becomes automated, we will see tons of new users providing seemingly okay answers. This could flood the first and late answers queue, and if some bot gets past the first post, it could swamp the answers with ChatGPT in the hope to spread spammy and possibly malicious links. Because the answer looks (and possibly is) okay users could be misled. This would undermine the trustworthiness of the forum.

So, yes, I think we should take this issue seriously